# Why Perl regex doesn't match "\n" with a following character?

Tags: regex, perl

This is my file `foo.txt`:

```
a
b
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/\nb/z/g' foo.txt
```

Nothing changes in the file, while I'm expecting it to become:

```
az
```

Why? It's Perl v5.34.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The firs time you evaluate the substitution, you match against `a␊`. The second time, against `b␊`. So it doesn't match either times.

You want to match against the entire file. You can tell Perl to consider the entire file one line by using `-g` aka `-0777`.

```bash
perl -i -gpe's/\nb/z/g' foo.txt    # 5.36+
```

```bash
perl -i -0777pe's/\nb/z/g' foo.txt
```